# Text Must Begin With '{' Error parseing JSON in Java

Tags: java, org.json

I'm using org.json lib to parse my JSON string. My json string is from input stream. I'm reading the json string from input stream and passing it to JSONObject() constructor. 
But I'm getting the following exception:

`[2011-08-28 23:42:52,235] main INFO  - Task(): input = "{\"keyword\":\"xxxx"}"
[2011-08-28 23:42:52,238] main ERROR - Task(): Exception: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]`

I guess the problem is with the extra double quotes,`"` in my `input`.
When I use `new JSONObject("{\"keyword\":\"xxxx"}");`, it is working fine.

++++ UPDATE ++++

Here is my json string reading code:

```
    try {
        in = new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(is));

        int c;
        while (true) {
            c = in.read();
            if (c == '\r' || c == '\n')
                break;
            requestLine.append((char) c);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Task(): Exception: "+e.getMessage());
    }
    input = requestLine.toString();
    //input = "{\"keyword\":\"xxxx\"}"; //working fine
    logger.info("Task(): input = "+input);
    try{
        org.json.JSONObject json = new org.json.JSONObject(input);      
        keyword = json.getString("keyword");
    }catch(Exception e) {
        logger.error("Task(): Exception: "+e.getMessage());
    }


    logger.info("Task(): keyword = "+keyword);
```

Comment: *How* are you reading and logging the string? Show the code that reads the input and the code that caused that INFO output.

Comment: Hi @delnan, I have updated my question, please check once.

Comment: Well, I see what's causing the exception, but you already guessed that yourself. Your string contains quotes that shouldn't be there, and unless `requestLine` is of some type that magically adds quotes around the strings it collects, those quotes are the fault of whoever gives your program its input. If the quotes really are in the input, the input is invalid JSON and your code can't do anything about (except trying to hack around it).

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this by eliminating the leading and trailing quotes by 
`input = input.replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");`